# HTTP Multiple Port Forwarding with SOCAT/Bash

Tags: bash, socat

I am attempting to set up a shell script to listen on a port, forward to *n* different IP addresses, and return the result of one of those API calls.

If I have one IP address, the solution is straightforward with

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080,fork,reuseaddr,crlf tcp4:127.0.0.1:8000
```

Where a REST API is on port 8000, and I am listening on port 8080.

For the multiple IP case, it seems like I need to use `tee` in some capacity to split into multiple API calls, as such:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:8080,fork,reuseaddr,crlf - | tee \
      >(socat - tcp4:127.0.0.1:8000 | cat; echo "This ends") \
      >(socat - tcp4:127.0.0.1:8000 | cat; echo "This ends too")
      >/dev/null
```

While I am able to print out the API calls from inside and the inner `socat` calls terminate (as `This ends` and `This ends too` are both getting printed when making a call on port 8080), the outer `socat` call does not return anything. Is there a way to return one of the `tee` values for the outer `socat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential solution to the problem is to create a handler script that takes the TCP-listen input and handles it.

router.sh:

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork,reuseaddr EXEC:"bash -e ./route_handler.sh"
```

route_handler.sh:

```
tee >(socat - TCP4:127.0.0.1:8001 >> /dev/null) | socat - TCP4:127.0.0.1:8000
```

When port `8080` is hit, the results are sent to the localhost ports `8000` and `8001` are called. The output from port `8000` is returned to the TCP listener.